# Is buffering possible in WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc

Is it possible to buffer the video/audio in WebRTC (of course, having then a delay on the other side) to improve the quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no exact way to fully control this, but there are some settings in the Opus codec that can influence it, like, minptime, ptime, maxptime. Please check https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-spittka-payload-rtp-opus-03#page-12 for more info.

Answer (score 1):

WebRtc does buffering automatically when it is necessary. You don't have to think about it.

Comment: I know that WebRTC does buffering, but how can you control it? Usually there's a trade-off between delay and quality. How can I control this?
I suspect that a longer buffer will improve quality, but then a longer delay will be introduced.

Comment: WebRTC makes the best decision for you.

Comment: @AdrianBer how exactly would a longer buffer improve quality?

Comment: Buffer will improve as any cache will. Of course a very long buffer will not improve things.

Comment: @AndreyKon, there is actually a way to do this. I'll post an answer on this.