# Add delay with WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc, video-conferencing

Can you add delay with WebRTC?  I want to set up video-conferencing with a constant and consistent delay.  For example, 4s each way.  I'd want the client to buffer the video and audio so that if you say something the and the other person replies instantly on hearing it, then you hear their response exactly 4s after you spoke for the first time.

Comment: If you had a 4s delay each way, then you would hear their response 8s after you spoke, not 4.

Comment: May I ask what is the reason and use case behind?

Comment: I want to make something for singing rounds over the Internet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change playout delay in WebRTC stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56510151/change-playout-delay-in-webrtc-stream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffering is possible in WebRTC - see [Is buffering possible in WebRTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130262/is-buffering-possible-in-webrtc). Unfortunately not to the level that you want.

It might be possible to do this as an effect with WebAudio, but then you won't have video.